# Preparing for a Penetration Test

Tags: wordpress, security, content-management-system, penetration-testing

I have made the case for using WordPress as a CMS for an important project.

IT has challenged me to build out this base WP installation alongside the local (WAMP) served intranet and lock it down the best I can. They will then attack the installation with enterprise level penetration testing software.

I am only privy to a minimum amount of details however some security tools I am up against have been mentioned and will be used in conjunction with enterprise level software:

1. Kali.org
2. Tools from [darknet.org.uk](http://www.darknet.org.uk/category/web-hacking/)
3. Watabo

**What I've done:**
Wiped all basic WP out-of-the-box data such as Administrator username, changed login page URL, removed ajax calls, leveraged all options within [iThemes Security](https://ithemes.com) plugin (which is pretty impressive) and a few of my own.

**My question is** for *advanced* advice on securing WordPress running 2015 theme and its PHP framework and Database. Proper htaccess configuration and possible pitfalls. Advice on any *advanced* methods of securing a website where it's likely to fail a pen test.

Comment: If you want to be really tricky, put the public-facing stuff behind a static cache like Varnish.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to make a website completely invulnerable, especially if you have chosen Wordpress.

You should update your Wordpress website constantly. It means that you have to follow all the updates and install them immediately. Sometimes it's not easy to do, if everything is working as it should, and the database is not small. Wordpress is the most popular open source CMS in the world and many people want to crack it, write crawlers which are searching vulnerabilities online etc.

**Simple steps to increase the security of any website:**

1. Close a port if you don't use it or install firewall, tcpwrapped etc.
2. Don't use FTP, ever. Use SSH instead.
3. Don't make rights 777 on the whole folder. Make it 555 and when you need to upload some image or something else change the rights to 777 or 755 (if you do it by ssh). After doing your job change rights back to 555. Nobody couldn't upload payload or other malicious code to your website through the front end if it's not allowed for writing.
4. Check your website for sql injection vulnerability.
5. Don't use simple passwords. You could even change your passwords every month.
6. Don't duplicate passwords.
7. Regularly update your software.
8. For back end security you could use some IDS, for example Snort - https://www.snort.org/, but it's not easy to configure properly. Furthermore you should understand how a network works, tcp/ip, attack types and so much more.
9. Use OpenBSD as your server operating system if you do not understand the information security well. It was created with an emphasis on increased security.
10. Take some network scanner (for example nmap) and test your server for vulnerabilities.

**Finally**: I wouldn't recommend to use Wordpress for the reliable security :) and to say more I need to take a look at the website.